# Finding supremum and infimum

Tags: supremum-and-infimum, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Let  $A = \{\frac{x}{2} - \lfloor\frac{x+1}{2}\rfloor  : x \in \mathbb{R}   \}$

Does **supremum** and **infimum** of $A$ exist ? If the answer is yes then find them .

My try : I rewrite the expression $\frac{x}{2} - (\lfloor 2x \rfloor - \lfloor x \rfloor)$ but it doesn't help really . Also I substituted $x$ with $n + p $ which $n$ is an integer and $0\le p \lt 1$ and wasn't helpful again .

Comment: Sketching the graph $f(x)=\frac{x}{2}-\left\lfloor\frac{x+1}{2}\right\rfloor$ might help (at least to get an intuition for what the answer should be). In addition, letting $x=a+b$ where $a$ and $b$ are the integer and fractional parts of $x$ may also help (or some similar substitution).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: If $y = \frac{x+1}{2}$  then $\frac{x}{2}-\lfloor\frac{x+1}{2}\rfloor = y-\lfloor y\rfloor-1/2$. Can you the supremum and infimum?

Comment: Yes , Thanks a lot . It's great !

Answer (score 4):

**Hint 1:** Show that on $[-1,1)$, $\left\lfloor\frac{x+1}2\right\rfloor=0$.

**Hint 2:** Show that $\frac{x}2 - \left\lfloor\frac{x+1}2\right\rfloor$ has a period of $2$.

Comment: Very useful hints . Thanks !